# Rails update model without edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update something from my view. The fact is for this model, the only field updatable is a boolean that goes from true to false and vice-versa.

That's why I don't want to go through a form in a edit view/controller method.

Here's my button :

```
 link_to 'Disable', myModel_path(id: @something.id), method: :put
 # I checked, the id is the right one
```

And here's the controller method I want to go through

```
# in myModel
def update
   m = myModel.find(params[:id])

   m.update(booleanField: !m.booleanField)

   render nothing: true
end
```

Also in route I did something like this :

```
resources :myModels   # with plural
```

Right now I am having an error that says bad route... I think the problem comes from the path of my link_to in my view.

```
No route matches [PUT] "/myModels"
```

What I'm trying to do is to go through the UPDATE controller method and stay in the same page (that i'll reload with some JS with onclick) so I can update my model without giving some troubles to my users.

Any help ? :)

EDIT : Here's the rake routes :

```
           myModels GET    /myModels(.:format)                                     myModels#index
                    POST   /myModels(.:format)                                     myModels#create
        new_myModel GET    /myModels/new(.:format)                                 myModels#new
       edit_myModel GET    /myModels/:id/edit(.:format)                            myModels#edit
            myModel GET    /myModels/:id(.:format)                                 myModels#show
                    PATCH  /myModels/:id(.:format)                                 myModels#update
                    PUT    /myModels/:id(.:format)                                 myModels#update
                    DELETE /myModels/:id(.:format)                                 myModels#destroy
```

(I checked the plurality twice ;) )

Comment: What is the exact error? Please post it in the question.

Comment: Of course, did not think it was this relevant ^^', edited.

Comment: There is a typo in your routes, it should be `resources` with a single 's', not two. Not sure if the issue is with he question or the actual file.

Comment: What is the value of `@something.id`?

Comment: @taglia It's a typo in the question. Sorry about that. I have all the routes "resources" create..

Comment: @Parvan The id is something like 250, I checked with my sql DB is the good id.

Comment: Can you post the `rake routes` output in the question?

Comment: Did the error tells you anything about ***missing key :id***?

Comment: Try like this `myModel_url(@something.id)` @Naarsh

Comment: No missing key :id in the server nor the browser...

Comment: @Narasimha Reddy Thanks a lot, it did do the trick !! :) I can do an answer if anybody has the same question :)

Comment: @Naarsh :)  wokay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having the same troubles, as per Narasimha's comment here's what you need to put in the view helper link_to :

```
link_to 'Disable', myModel_url(@something.id), method: :put
```